# Vote to close or flag as spam (or both?)

Tags: support, vote-to-close, flags, spam

If I've voted for a spam question to be closed, should it still be flagged for a moderator as spam?

I figured that, regardless of the closed or open status of a question, the site/mods should be made aware of problematic account, but if it is redundant to do so, I'll let you save that spot in the flag queue for something else.

I looked around for duplicates but most of them centered around flagging questions that weren't going to make it to 5 close votes or the closing reason of "spam" that "has ceased to be."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should always *flag* spam.

All other actions as are entirely optional. For example, voting to close a spam question (assuming you've already flagged it!) isn't going to do any harm, but probably won't achieve much either (unless the question ultimately *isn't* spam, but just off-topic, in which case you might still help close it).

But, just taking secondary actions (like closing) *without* flagging will potentially slow-down the removal of the offending content.

---

And, in case you are not aware, after receiving 3 spam flags a post is removed from the front page, and after receiving 6 users flag something as spam it is automatically incinerated - zero moderator intervention required.

For further information see the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) page [How does the spam flag work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work).

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about the removal from the front page after 3, but I knew about the 6 flags consequence.

Answer (score 9):

If enough number of people flag a post as spam - the post gets deleted and a -100 rep penalty is imposed. That doesn't happen if you vote to close.

**If a post is spam - flag it as so.**

Answer (score 5):

Spam should not be closed, it should be deleted. If a post accumulates enough spam flags it is automatically deleted and the owner gets -100 reputation. A moderator can accelerate the process, but the community can delete questions on its own.

If a user repeatedly posts spam, you can additionally flag for moderator attention (using the free-form flag). Usually the spam flags are enough to get the attention of a mod, but if there is a pattern some more explanation might be helpful.

Comment: A good point about the free-form flag (something ate my other comment).