# Should the spam handling guidance be consolidated into a single post?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

As a regular SPAM flagger based on the reports of the [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) I run now and then into posts that not only receive spam flags but also close votes, an edit or comments and I imagine NAA/VLQ flags as well.

Based on some sort of consensus in the [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1982255#1982255) it was decided that spam posts should only receive a spam flag and nothing more, backed by the following posts:

- [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited)
- [Vote to close or flag as spam (or both?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96007/vote-to-close-or-flag-as-spam-or-both/96008#96008)
- [Recent Mass Football Spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam)
- [Why shouldn't I downvote spam that I've already flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193916/why-shouldnt-i-downvote-spam-that-ive-already-flagged)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)

All those questions/FAQ and their answers have value but I couldn't find an single answer that clearly states/explains said consensus.

I would like to discuss if the consensus to **ONLY** raise a spam flag is agreed upon by the community at large?  And if so, if this outcome should be edited into one of the existing posts?

The most logical place seems to be the [FAQ answer on spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/158100) but that answer is busy with describing spam and offensive flags. I don't fancy adding more noise to it.

One of the benefits of having a single post is that you can link *offenders* to a single post, instead of a train of links that the reader need to cherry pick to get the message.

Comment: I think the difference between the support this has got compared to the SO counterparts http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317277/show-a-warning-when-someone-uses-a-custom-close-reason-containing-the-word-spam, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327636/educating-people-to-flag-spam-and-not-vote-to-close is that the smaller communities probably have a tighter user base that is more aware of spam flagging, not as huge as SO . This high rep users on the smaller sites prob participate more in moderation, so they may not experience the same problem with it. Just a hypothesis.